# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException with spring and gwt (requestFactory)

Tags: spring, gwt, requestfactory

I get this error with a gwt (using requestfactory) and spring

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [org.calibra.server.service.AccountService] is defined: expected single bean but found 0: 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:271)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1101)
at org.calibra.server.SpringServiceLocator.getInstance(SpringServiceLocator.java:24)
at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.LocatorServiceLayer.createServiceInstance(LocatorServiceLayer.java:56)
```

My service locator

```
public class SpringServiceLocator implements ServiceLocator {
    @Override
    public Object getInstance(Class<?> clazz) {
        ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(                
            RequestFactoryServlet.getThreadLocalServletContext());
        return context.getBean(clazz);
    }
}
```

My spring service

```
@Service
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService{
     @Override
     public void addNewAccount(Account account) {
       ...
     }

     @Override
     public List<Account> loadAllAccounts() {
        ...
     }

}
```

Gwt requestContext, reference my spring service

```
@Service(value=AccountService.class, locator=SpringServiceLocator.class)
public interface AccountRequest extends RequestContext {

    Request<Void> addNewAccount(AccountProxy account);

    Request<List<AccountProxy>> loadAllAccounts();

}
```

my web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>gwtRequest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>gwtRequest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/gwtRequest</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>welcomeGWT.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I don't understand how i can have 0 AccountService beans ?

i tried to add in the dispatcher-servlet

```
<bean id="accountService" class="org.calibra.server.service.AccountServiceImpl"/>
```

I got the same result

Any idea?

edit: if somebody have a full complete example, that could be useful.

Comment: Did you declare your RequestFactory servlet on your web.xml?

Comment: i have <br/>  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>gwtRequest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you have a servlet-mapping missing. Please look here : http://crazygui.wordpress.com/2011/09/23/spring-gwt-integration-using-the-requestfactory-api/ for more details

Comment: hard to say, the link don't give a lot of information and their web.xml is not available

Comment: Your web.xml file seems correct. Sorry I can't pinpoint the exact problem. When I have the noSuchBeanException, it is usually because Spring can't find the bean he's trying to inject in the context of the application. Are you sure the bean definition is in your application context?

Comment: in my dispatcher-servlet.xml, i have:     <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.calibra" />

Comment: my applicationContext.xml file is empty (don't use a db for the thest).

Answer (score 0):

I think using the ContextLoaderListener alone is not enough as you don't seem to have the DispatcherServlet in use (have you?).
The following lines work for me:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springRequestContextFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springRequestContextFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/gwtRequest</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: no, i don't have a DispatcherServlet, so my dispatcher-servlet is surely not loaded. I will need to move the content of this file to applicationContext.xml and see if that work... after i will try your solution

Comment: I tried to put config annotation in the applicationContext.xml without success. I tried also your solution without success.

Comment: can you post your web.xml, applicationContext.xml and dispatcherServlet.xml

Comment: Looking at your configuration it seems as if the dispatcher-servlet.xml is not processed as in your web.xml the parameter contextConfigLocation only refers to the applicationContext.xml. Maybe you can merge both files into one to be sure the spring config is correct? At first, please make sure your Spring setup is working (setting the logger level to DEBUG helps). You might also set a breakpoint at your service class to see if it's loaded at all.

Comment: i only have: <context:component-scan base-package="com.calibra" />   in my dispatcherServlet.xml. so i put this command to my applicationcontext and got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this question in a couple of other places. You should try explicity defining the AccountServiceImpl as a bean in your applicationContext.xml (not the dispatch-servlet.xml) first and see if you still get the error, if you don't then you know it's that you're missing the component-scan in your application context xml which is what I think is the case.

hope this helps

Comment: i think service extends component... just more specialized

Comment: You're right, I just remembered that too...I think the issue is that user hadn't put the component scan in their application context xml